# How would you efficiently vectorize that kind of operation using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

### Input data

Produce n matrices of a given size (here, 3x2). I also chose n=25, but I let n to lay the emphasis on the fact that what we have is a bunch of matrices.

```
import numpy as np
n = 25
data = np.random.rand(n, 3, 2)
```

This is just a format example : I can't change it. Or if I do, one must take into account the computational cost of this change.

### Current implementation

What I want to achieve atomically is:

```
output = []
for datum in data: # This outputs on (3x2) matrix after the other
    d0 = datum[0]
    dr = datum[1:]
    output.append(dr-d0)
```

or, in a faster fashion:

```
output = [dr-d0 for (dr, d0) in zip(datum[:,0], datum[:,1:])]
```

### Problem

This is too slow and:

```
output = datum[:,1:] - datum[:,0]
```

does not work since the behavior of the subtraction operation is not well defined in that case. Plus, this kind of slicing is not very efficient.

Cython/Nuitka/PyPy and the likes are possible solutions, but I'd like to stick with raw Numpy for now, if possible. Maybe some kind of function that can be applied on elements of the outer loop of a numpy array very quickly without the overhead of python stuff...

The `np.vectorize` function doesn't work on:

```
def get_diff(mat):
    return mat[1:] - mat[0]
```

So I invoke ye, High Priests of Numpy, servants of Python to enlighten my poor soul!

**EDIT:**

### XY Problem

(I didn't know it had a name)

What I actually want to do is to determine the content (read "volume") of a lot of simplices (read "tetrahedra"). The easiest and most efficient way to do it, AFAIK is to calculate:

```
np.linalg.det(mat[:1]-mat[0])
```

Then let me rephrase my question: how can I efficiently compute the content of any ensemble of simplices of dimension k using plain python and numpy?

Comment: I'm going to invoke my new favourite concept (thanks @alKid). This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Trying to understand your code, for each 3x2 sub-matrix, you want a list/array containing the first column subtracted from the second two columns?

Comment: @Mr E : Corrected and yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest `data[:,1:] - data[:,0,None]`.  The `None` creates a new axis (officially you're supposed to use `np.newaxis`, which makes it very clear what you're doing), and then the subtraction will behave the way you want it to.

Correcting what I think are errors in your list comprehension:

```
def loop(data):
    output = []
    for datum in data: # This outputs on (3x2) matrix after the other
        d0 = datum[0]
        dr = datum[1:]
        output.append(dr-d0)
    return output

def listcomp(data):
    output = [dr-d0 for (d0, dr) in zip(data[:,0], data[:,1:])]
    return output

def sub(data):
    output = data[:,1:] - data[:,0,None]
    return output
```

we have

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = 25
>>> data = np.random.rand(n, 3, 2)
>>> res_loop = loop(data)
>>> res_listcomp = listcomp(data)
>>> res_sub = sub(data)
>>> np.allclose(res_loop, res_listcomp)
True
>>> np.allclose(res_loop, res_sub)
True
>>> 
>>> %timeit loop(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop
>>> %timeit listcomp(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop
>>> %timeit sub(data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Just wanted to point out that the key thing used here to get the vectorization working is called [broadcasting](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting). Broadcasting is a super-useful feature.

Comment: One order of magnitude, this is great! I didn't know I could use None like this. And actually, when I raised n to 800, I had a x100 improvement. This is the greatest thing I've learnt this week. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for the link Mr E. Definitely a great source of information too!

Comment: @Gael: sure.  Mr E's suggestion is a great one -- it's worth spending the time reading through the tutorial to get a grasp of how broadcasting works. The downside is that it makes certain things so easy that it's hard to switch to environments without it..